# Python requests обработка ошибки

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, requests, обработка-ошибок

Здравствуйте, пишу парсер. И иногда выскакивает ошибка ConnectionError.
Но я ее никак не могу поймать, что я не делаю не так.

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/test5.py", line 194, in <module>
    start_parse_object()
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/test5.py", line 113, in start_parse_object
    for _ in executor.map(parse_object, object_urls):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/test5.py", line 82, in parse_object
    r =request_json(url)
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/test5.py", line 140, in request_json
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

И код:

```
def request_json(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            log.info("Ошибка, Код ответа: %s", r.status)
            time.sleep(1)
            request_json(url)
        else:
            return r.json()
    except ConnectionError:
        log.info("Ошибка ConnectionError")
        time.sleep(1)
        request_json(url)

def request(url):
    try:
        r=requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code!=200:
            log.info("Ошибка, Код ответа: %s",r.status)
            time.sleep(1)
            request(url)
        else:
            return r
    except ConnectionError:
        log.info("Ошибка ConnectionError")
        time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(request(url))
```

Ошибка выскакивает, в использовании повторного запроса в обработке исключения. Понимаю что там тоже нужно try catch, но хотелось бы чтобы делался запрос, пока не пропала ошибка, наподобие функции высчитывания факториала, которая сама себя вызывает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно рекурсию использовать – достаточно цикла. Вот пример:

```
def request(url):
    while True:
        try:
            rs = requests.get(url)
            if rs.status_code != 200:
                log.info("Ошибка, Код ответа: %s", rs.status)
                time.sleep(1)

                # Попробуем снова на следующей итерации цикла
                continue
            
            # Если дошли до сюда, значит ошибок не было
            return rs

        except ConnectionError:
            # Выводим свое сообщение плюс стек трассы
            log.exception("Ошибка ConnectionError")
            time.sleep(1)


def request_json(url):
    return request(url).json()
```

---

У меня в [скриптах подобный код есть](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/Check%20with%20notification/all_common.py#L82) для отправки смс.

Comment: К сожалению ошибка не исправилась. Может ошибка в другом?

Comment: Может нужно отлавливать urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError, либо http.client.RemoteDisconnected?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на `except Exception as e` и выводите тип `print(type(e))`. В принципе, вам не помешает ловить все исключения

Comment: спасибо, проблему решил. А вот что выводилась, сначала сама ошибка, потом тип:   ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
<class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'>

Comment: Мне вот интересно, почему тот вариант не отловил ошибку

Comment: возможно, не тот ConnectionError в except ловился. Попробуйте полностью прописывать `except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:`